# I have 50 rep. Why can I not start a bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty, privileges

[The help center explains](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) that the minimum offer for a bounty is 50 reputation. I have enough repuation to do so now, but I do not see a link to start a bounty under any question, no matter how old. Why not?

I'm somewhat desperate to receive an answer to [a question of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298019/test-individual-categories-in-a-contingency-table-for-significance) and would like to offer a bounty once it is two days old to draw some attention to it, but I am confused that I appear not to have that option.

Comment: You need at least 75. https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: Thank you, @NickCox, I see. I may have overlooked it, but if not I believe it would be useful if that information were given on the help page I linked to as well, maybe in the list at the beginning of the page.

Comment: You may already find an answer among these: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi+squared+post+hoc ... or these https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi+square+post+hoc